# How to escape special characters in a file parsed by PHP parse_ini_file function?

Tags: php, encoding, special-characters

I'd like to keep a certain string in a configuration file, that is to be parsed by PHP [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function. However, this string contains some special characters (with codes like `0x2C` or `0x3D`) that need to be encoded in some way. Is there any way to write a special character with a hex code in such a file?

Comment: Maybe you should say what the actual problem is when you use those characters inside the file to be parsed?

Comment: As long as you escape them properly... everything is possible. Options are quite a few.

Comment: @arkascha, I need to keep a certain binary key from a third-party application ([Map Quest](http://mapquest.com) if you're curious). I know how to escape these characters in PHP code, but I think this kind of data should not be embedded in code. At the same time, I'd like the `.ini` file to be legible.

Comment: @JanDvorak, yep, that's what I'm asking: what options?

Comment: [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) / [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: [`base64_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) / [`base64_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Comment: [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) / [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) / [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @JanDvorak, I was hoping there's some magical way to escape a character that would allow `parse_ini_file()` to automatically read it as binary data... Oh well, maybe it's better this way. Thanks for your reply, maybe you should list it as an actual answer?

Comment: `Note:

If a value in the ini file contains any non-alphanumeric characters it needs to be enclosed in double-quotes (").`, so this is the proper way to ini-escape, but I can't find the proper way to escape strings with double-quotes

Comment: @JanDvorak That is mentioned in one of the examples below.

Comment: With "the actual problem" I asked for what happens when you do no escaping whatsoever. You repeated how you want to solve the problem, not what the actual probem is.

Comment: @arkascha, sorry if I confused you. The problem is I need this file to contain these characters, but want them in escaped form so that they will be readable and recognizable.

Comment: Sure, I got that. It is all sorted out now. But for future question please don't specify a solution attempt in the question (not only), but the actual problem. Here the problem would have been: what does actually happen when you run your code as it is? And why is that not the result you expected/want to have? _That_ would have been a good starting point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way to escape INI values is to enclose them in `"double quotes"`. If your string doesn't contain double quotes, you can use it in as a value enclosed in double quotes.

Escaping single quotes with a backslash seems to work as long as there are not two consecutive double quotes in the value, as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#100046

If you want to do your own escaping, you certainly can:

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) / [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) escapes `<`,`>`,`&` and `"`.

[`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) / [`html_entitity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) will escape very aggresively (but also very safely) to HTML entities

[`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) / [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) will escape all special characters except `_-~.`.

[`base64_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) / [`base64_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) will ensure the encoded string contains only alphanumeric characters and `+=/`. This might be optimal for encoding binary data but doesn't preserve readability.