# PHP - MultiLanguage support

Tags: php, ini

I am trying to add multi language support for my website, like this:

`Language.php`:

```
class lang {

    private $lang = null;

    function __construct($lang) {
        global $module;
        $module['lang'] = true;
        $this->lang = parse_ini_file("includes/languages/{$lang}.ini");
    }


    public function xlate($str) {

        $arg_count = func_num_args();

        if ($arg_count > 1) {
            $params = func_get_args();

            // strip first arg
            array_shift($params);
        } else {
            $params = array();
        }

        $out_str = isset($this->lang[$str]) ? $this->lang[$str] : null;

        if (!$out_str) {
            throw new exception("Lang String Not Found: $str");
            $this->lang = parse_ini_file("includes/languages/en_gb.ini");
        }

        return vsprintf($out_str, $params);
    }
}
```

I then have my language variables stored in a ini file:

`en_gb.ini`:

```
Support = Support
Quick Menu = Quick Menu
HOME_MAIN_TITLE = You will Get Paid
```

Then I use it like:

```
echo $lang->xlate("Support");
echo $lang->xlate("Quick Menu");
echo $lang->xlate("HOME_MAIN_TITLE");
```

Which works. However, whenever I pass a `'` character in the language, it doesn't work:

```
HOME_MAIN_TITLE = You'll Get Paid
```

It echoes the text until the `'` character:

```
You
```

And then it stops.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try adding a backslash before the `'` so it becomes `\'`. This is known as an escape character https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: Look at the text highlighting. Also the line after your throw statement will never be executed.

Comment: @KevinPei Adding a backslash doesn't work. It will just print: You\

Comment: @Rangad Text highlightning?

Comment: @oliverbj apologies for jumping to conclusions... this question seems to suggest that enclosing the entire value in double quotes make work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306821/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-a-file-parsed-by-php-parse-ini-file-function

Comment: You'll see that the `'` is treated as a string delimiter. See: https://3v4l.org/81dFo#v5329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, all strings in `.ini` file should be wrapped into `"double quotes"`. This will fix issue.

May I suggest you to look at something generic and community approved. Like https://github.com/symfony/translation (it has `.ini` loader inside)